# jquery how to toggle class parent element and change Text

Tags: jquery

How to toggle the parent's class when when click child button and How to change Text?

this is my source

```
<div class="list3"> 
    <table>
    <tr class="use"> 
        <td>
            <a href="#">Yes</a>
         </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="notUse"> 
        <td><a href="#">No</a></td>
    </tr> 
    <tr class="notUse"> 
        <td><a href="#">No</a></td>
    </tr> 
    </table>
</div>
```

This is what I want to do...

1. Click "Yes" button change parents TR element's class to "notUse" and Change Button text as "No"
2. Click "No" button change parents TR element's class to "use" and Change Button text as "Yes"

Comment: Step 1. jQuery is overhead for this. Step 2. Write some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `.toggleClass(class1 class2)` signature,

```
$('.list3 a').click(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   var xText =  $this.text();
   $this.closest('tr').toggleClass('notUse use')
   $this.text(xText==="Yes"?"No":"Yes");
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/9AUxw/)

Comment: Wont that just toggle both classes at the same time?

Comment: No, it will toggle within the supplied classes, please see the demo and inspect it.. :)

Comment: @user3400080 glad to help..! consider this as accepted if you wish.,.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.list3 a').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.parent().parent().toggleClass('notUse use');
    $this.text($this.text() == "Yes" ? "No" : "Yes");
});
```

Comment: This will change the text of the tr..!